# How to sort through a block of string text

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

Trying to use data from a basketball stats site for a project. I just the need the data to be useable for manipulation (names in one box, correlating stats in the other) as it is right now its just a long list of strings.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const fs = require('fs')
const url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2023_per_game.html';
    axios(url)
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)
            const fullTable = $('.full_table').text()
            console.log(typeof fullTable);
            })
            .catch(console.error);
```

Tried a couple of different things (i have 2 other versions of this) and either no data is moved/printed out or it simply gives me all of the data as one big block of strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's by design that you're getting a long string when calling `text()`

```js
const fullTable = $('.full_table').text()
```

## text

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

From the [docs](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/api/classes/Cheerio#text)

While `text` is useful, it's not what you need. To get the stats, you'll process *each* `tr.full_table` element and extract the contents to an object array, which you can easily query. To do this efficiently see the [`extract`](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/advanced/extract) method for more information and code examples.

## extract

> The extract method in Cheerio allows you to extract data from an HTML document and store it in an object. The method takes a map object as a parameter, where the keys are the names of the properties to be created on the object, and the values are the selectors or descriptors to be used to extract the values.